# Posicionar Flechas en Slick-Slider para avanzar y retroceder

Tags: html5, css3, plugin, slider

Estoy intentado agregar flechas a un slick slider he visto preguntas como esta [Change the Arrow buttons in Slick slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876185/change-the-arrow-buttons-in-slick-slider) y esta [Change Slick Slider Arrow Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979306/change-slick-slider-arrow-position), pero sigo sin tener el resultado deseado.

Quisiera que mis flechas aparezcan a los lados de mi slider, donde usualmente aparecen, he intentado agregar:

```
.paginator{
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.paginator .slick-prev{
  right:10px;
}
.paginator .slick-next{
  right:0;
}
```

Tambien he intentado hacerlo con `Flex-box` y aunque puedan aparecer a los lados del slider no estan dentro del slider.

```
.paginator{
    top: 0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Agregando la siguiente configuracion en mi funcion del slick slider `arrows:true` y `prevArrow: $('.slick-prev')`, `nextArrow: $('.slick-next')`:

```
$(".slider").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      autoplay: true,
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      pauseOnFocus: false,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      prevArrow: $('.slick-prev'),
      nextArrow: $('.slick-next'),
      
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          dots: false,
          arrows: false,
          infinite: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }]
    });
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h2,
p {
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.paginator{
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.paginator .slick-prev{
  right:10px;
}
.paginator .slick-next{
  right:0;
}



.slider {
    max-width: 8000px;
    width: 115%;
    margin: 15px auto;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    /* box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26); */
    /*h v b s*/
}

.slick-slider button {
    display: none !important;
}

.slick-slide {
    color: #333;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-slide .desc {
    opacity: 0;
    margin: -20px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.slick-slide .desc>* {
    transition: all 900ms ease;
}

.slick-slide .desc h2 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size:25px;
}

.slick-slide .desc p {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;
}

.slick-dots {
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-dots li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 5px;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active {
    background: var(--yellow-color);
}

.slick-dots button {
    display: none;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
    /* background: blue;*/
}

.slick-slide {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.slick-current {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.slick-current .desc {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slick-current .desc h2 {
    left: 0;
}

.slick-current .desc p {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

.mybtn {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid #18c495;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #18c495;
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
}

.mybtn-preview01 {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid var(--blue-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--blue-color);
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
    font-family: 'KGBSpace';
}

.mybtn-preview02 {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid var(--sweet-potato-bg);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--sweet-potato-bg);
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
    font-family: 'KGBSpace';
}

.mybtn-preview03 {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid var(--red-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--red-color);
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
    font-family: 'KGBSpace';
}

.mybtn-preview04 {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 4px solid var(--purple-sweetBTN-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--purple-sweetBTN-color);
    font-size: .6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    pointer-events: initial;
    font-family: 'KGBSpace';
}


@media(max-width:1366px) {
    .slider {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media(max-width:720px){
    .slick-slide .desc h2{
        font-size:21px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:720px){
    .mybtn-preview04{
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .mybtn-preview03{
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .mybtn-preview02{
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .mybtn-preview01{
        font-size: .5em;
    }
    .mybtn{
         font-size: .5em;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css">


<section class="slider">

  <div id="product1">
    <a href="products/newURL.html">
      <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/b5355/304/Scenery_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Fields_Sky_Sun_519151_600x800.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <h2 style="color:var(--blue-color)">Product1</h2>
      <a href="#" class="mybtn-preview01">View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="product2">
    <a href="products/newURL.html">
      <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/b5355/304/Scenery_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Fields_Sky_Sun_519151_600x800.jpg">
    </a>

    <div class="desc">
      <h2 style="color:var(--sweet-potato-bg)">Product2</h2>
      <a href="#" class="mybtn-preview02">View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="product3">
    <a href="products/newURL.html">
      <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/b5355/304/Scenery_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Fields_Sky_Sun_519151_600x800.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <h2 style="color:var(--red-color)">Product3</h2>
      <a href="#" class="mybtn-preview03">View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="product4">
    <a href="products/newURL.html">
      <img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/b5355/304/Scenery_Sunrises_and_sunsets_Fields_Sky_Sun_519151_600x800.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <h2 style="color:var(--red-color)">Product4</h2>
      <a href="#" class="mybtn-preview03">View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  

</section>

<div class="paginator">
        <div class="slick-prev"> prev </div>
        <div class="slick-next"> next </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<script>
  function createSlick() {

    $(".slider").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      autoplay: true,
      infinite: true,
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      pauseOnFocus: false,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      prevArrow: $('.slick-prev'),
            nextArrow: $('.slick-next'),
      
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          dots: false,
          arrows: false,
          infinite: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }]
    });

  }

  createSlick();

  $(window).on('resize', createSlick);

</script>
```

Debería de poner dentro de mi `section` el `div` con clase `.paginator` ?

Agradecería cualquier comentario.